# Migrate console C# to SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task

I have a C# console app that reads Excel data and reformats it/cleans it up. Finally, app writes data to 2 different CSV files. This console app. has :

1. Program.cs - contains Main method.
2. Row.cs - properties that split each row of data into separate columns.
3. Locations.cs - properties for working with locations (data is divided by regions/locations).
4. LocationsBuilder.cs - contains main logic where data cleaning and transformation occurs.

I would like to migrate all of the C# code into an SSIS C# Script Task, not sure how to do this as Script Task code seems to only 1 use 1 file for all code.

I would like, if possible, to have all code in 1 script so it works in SSIS Script Task.

Comment: Why do you want to migrate a working console app that doesn't even reference a database into a SSIS Script Task? That does not seem like a good idea to me

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, the console app reads an Excel file, applies special formatting and parsing and produces an output to a CSV file, CSV file is then used by SSIS to update the database. I am combining 2 separate processes/apps (C# console app and SSIS solution) into 1.

Comment: If this is a data integration process I recommend you refactor the entire process to import the Excel file directly into the database, (although that can be a difficult thing). With regards to multiple classes in one file - there is no problem doing that. You just need to make sure the entry point matches what SSIS expects. In the first instance you should paste all of your classes into the editor and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is a platform for ETL work. You can archive Excel to CSV format.

```
How to do it
1. Open Integration Services project / SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)
2. Create a new SSIS package
3. Add data flow and add those 2 files as datasource 
4. Add control flow accordingly if you have any conditional logic in console applicaiton.
5. Add output destination as CSV ouput
6. That's it
```

Comment: The console app parses and reformats the data to an CSV file. The ETL portion of existing SSIS solution grabs the file and inserts the data into the database. What I want to do is combine the functionality of both into 1 ETL solution.

The issue I am having is that I was able to put all my console app code into the Script Task (1 file, the default ScriptMain.cs). It builds w/o error, but, when ran it always fails. Inserting breakpoints don't work as it seems to fail inmediately when SSIS calls it. I get the generic message "DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code:.."

Comment: ... I suspect Script Task doesn't like have multiple classes in 1 file. I also tried leaving the code in separate files (like in the original console application), but this doesn't even build.

Answer (score 0):

**You can keep your code as it is**.

In the SSIS designer add a script task component, and copy all classes code inside the script *(You can create multiple class inside one cs file or add new classes to the project)*. And copy the main method code inside the main function in the script.

Or you can create a class library and use it inside the script task code.

**Helpful links**

- [how to create a class and methods inside a C# script task](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3fe77a3f-b9c2-4d63-9105-cb7d37495b14/how-to-create-a-class-and-methods-inside-a-c-script-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices)